# Bash prompt PS1 newline must be conditional

Tags: bash, terminal, conditional-statements

How do we have PS1 newline `\n` being conditional on whether previous Bash variable's one, as this cannot succeed:

`foo=`

```
 NEWLINE=
 #...
 ((foo)) && {
  THELINE=foobar
  NEWLINE='\n'
 }
```

`PS1='$(echo $THELINE)$NEWLINE\w-$ '`

if foo not 0 then THELINE is "foobar" with a newline, otherwise whatever THELINE is it musn't be given \n

sincere useful help valuable

`$.............``

Comment: Please read [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and then fix your variable names.

Comment: Do you want `foo` to be tested once where `PS1` is declared or every time the value of `PS1` is printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the logic directly in PS1 as :

```
PS1='$(((foo)) && echo $"foobar\n\r" || echo "no") \$ '
```

example:

```
$ PS1='$(((foo)) && echo $"foobar\n\r" || echo "no") \$ '
no $ foo=1
foobar
 $
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to make `bash` call a function before every prompt.

Unfortunately, I do not understand what you are trying to do so I can't show you exactly how to do what you want. This should get you started though:

```bash
prompt_cmd() {
    if [[ condition ]]; then
        PS1="true_prompt$ "
    else
        PS1="false_prompt$ "
    fi
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_cmd
```